# Random freezes and reboots AMD Ryzen

Tags: linux, kernel, reboot, freeze, amd

I have an AMD Ryzen 7 3800x with a MSI x570 mobo.

I suffer from random reboots and freezes on Linux. Windows works totally fine though.

I've searched on several forums and stackexchange threads, and none of the solutions work.

The problems happen both in a USB live media and my existing installation.
If I boot without any kernel parameters set, i get some "no irq handler for vector" and a reboot.
If the system is able to keep working a few more seconds, i get a "tsc marked as unstable" followed by a hard reboot.

So far, I've tried this approaches:

- pci=noaer, iommu=soft, pcie_aspm=off, processor.max_cstate=1, processor.max_cstate=5 (In all possible arrangements)
- disabling C state management in BIOS
- Disabling PSU idle power management in BIOS
- Lowering RAM speeds
- marking tsc=unstable

Memtest shows no errors, and I've already cleared my CMOS and changed the battery. Tried with incrementally removing RAM sticks too.

Sometimes, a kernel exception shows up, as if the kernel was trying to dereference NULL.
Another error that I seem to get randomly is:  kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 10: Machine Check: 0 Bank 0: baa0000000060185

I have no more ideas to test. I'll gladly anymore information needed.

Comment: Have you tried updating your BIOS to the latest version? Is your RAM on the QVL list?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have updated  my BIOS to the latest version, and rolled it back several versions just to see if I could narrow the issue, but no success. Happens with every BIOS version that I tried. And yes, my RAM is in the QVL

Comment: What kind of memory test have you used?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov both memtest86+ and windows memory tester. I can't use any linux tool since I'm unable to boot.

Comment: File a bug report at https://bugzilla.kernel.org - some very knowledgable people are over there.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I will, thank you for your help!

Comment: were you able to solve the issue @DavidMasedaNeira

Comment: @troy_achilies I ended up switching my Mobo for an Asus tuf x570 pro, and it has been working flawlessly eversince